# Load Requirejs module with relative path

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

i need a js module that loads a set of other modules, base on a config. Something like this structure

```
define(['json!config.json', function() {
   //load module on config.path + 'modulea' ;
   //load module on config.path + 'moduleb' ;
   doSomething(modulea,moduleb) ; 

}) ;
```

which is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define(['config.json'], function(config) {
    require.config({
        paths: {
        "modulea": config.path + "modulea",
        "moduleb": config.path + "moduleb"
    }
});
```

Then you can require your modules from anywhere you want, just make sure that the above is always executed first.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
define(['json!config.json', function(config) {
   require([config.path + 'modulea', config.path + 'moduleb'], function(modulea, moduleb) {
     doSomething(modulea, moduleb) ; 
   }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use script tag loading as long as you trust the source of the scripts. You can use a function like:

```
loadscript = function(url,callback,err) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src=url;
    if(typeof callback != 'undefined') { s.onload=callback; }
    if(typeof err != 'undefined') { s.onerror=err; }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s); //assuming you want the script tags in the document head
}
```

Comment: Why is this marked down with no explanation of the alleged defect?